# TURN-Server for RTCConfiguration

Tags: webrtc, turn

I'm wondering if it is possible to establish a WebRTC connection between two clients that have different turn servers configured. Does the specification state if the configuration has to be identical?
What happens when they both specify different servers? Will they choose random or is the connection impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configurations don't have to be identical. If both Peers require a relay connection the TURN servers will communicate directly to each other (via their allocation ports)

If you do end up using the same TURN server make sure you handle hairpinning properly!

Comment: Is that also the case if both TURN servers require credentials?

Comment: I've fleshed out my question here. (It seems reasonable to cross-post here as they're closely related): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63821947/is-it-possible-to-successfully-negotiate-a-webrtc-connection-between-peers-who-a